# Simple interest to compound interest in JAVA

Tags: java, finance

I need a java calculation for simple interest to compound interest, i have the amount of years,the principle amount and the simple interest rate. I cant find a calculation for it.

Comment: Try any one of the links on the right hand side of this page under "Related".

Comment: Google seems to be fine. At least, a search for "compound interest formula" gets plenty of hits.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference [this site](http://www.thecalculatorsite.com/articles/finance/compound-interest-formula.php) can be found by googling 'compound interest formula'

The formula for annual compound interest is A = P (1 + r/n) ^ nt

Where:

A = the future value of the investment/loan, including interest

P = the principal investment amount (the initial deposit or loan amount)

r = the annual interest rate (decimal)

n = the number of times that interest is compounded per year

t = the number of years the money is invested or borrowed for

Example:
If an amount of $5,000 is deposited into a savings account at an annual interest rate of 5%, compounded monthly, the value of the investment after 10 years can be calculated as follows...

P = 5000

r = 0.05

n = 12

t = 10

If we plug those figures into the formula, we get:

A = 5000 (1 + 0.05 / 12) ^ 12(10) = 8235.05.

So, the investment balance after 10 years is $8,235.05.

Comment: I need a compound interest percentage, not the final ammount